# Conditional Split Explained

Tags: ssis

Trying to understand what the following conditional split expression is trying to do:

ISNULL(Employee_ID_WD) || (RIGHT(REPLACENULL(Employee_ID_WD,"0"),LEN(REPLACENULL(Employee_ID,"0"))) != REPLACENULL(Employee_ID,"0"))

I am new to SSIS, can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a relatively straight forward expression when you break it down.

To put it succinctly (tl;dr), if the `Employee_ID_WD` is null OR the `Employee_ID` value is not in the `Employee_ID_WD` value, then return `true`. Otherwise, return `false`.

Details:

The first part, `ISNULL(Employee_ID_WD)`, checks to see of the `Employee_ID_WD` is null. If it is, the expression will return true, right away. The reason for that is the `||` right after. This is called a logical or. If you see this in many programming it indicates that the programmer wants to the expression to return right away if any part of it before the `||` is true. In other words, if something before the `||` is true, start doing what I need you to do, there is no sense in checking anything in this expression, I know what I need to know in order to move on. This is referred to as short-circuit evaluation. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

If the `Employee_ID_WD` is not null, we move on to the next part of the expression.

This part:

```
(RIGHT(REPLACENULL(Employee_ID_WD,"0"),LEN(REPLACENULL(Employee_ID,"0")))
```

is grabbing the characters on the right side of the `Employee_ID_WD`. The number of characters it is asking for is what is returned from the `LEN` (length) function being run on the `Employee_ID`. Also, both parts of this are checking if the value they pass in is null, as indicated by the `REPLACENULL` function. If they are null, a string with the value 0 is returned. This is done in case one of the values are null, this way you get a true value comparison. Using the `REPLACENULL` function in all parts of this expression makes it that much more robust, meaning inconsistencies with data will be handled without something error-ing out, or giving in consistent results in the end.

The results from the part above are compared to `REPLACENULL(Employee_ID,"0")`. If the part above and this are not equal (`!=` is not equal to), then the expression returns true.

[SSIS Expression Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141671.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. This answer provides the clarity I sought.